# How to get extended public key from extended private key in bip39?

Tags: private-key, ecdsa, bip39

I have root key, and I want derivate child key from it. As I understood, I need parent key`s fingerprint, which is first 32 bits of ripemd160, of sha256 of public key. How can I get public key from private key? Per the [BIP39 standard](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#key-identifiers)

> Extended keys can be identified by the Hash160 (RIPEMD160 after SHA256) of the serialized ECDSA public key K, ignoring the chain code.

So, I need serialized ECDSA public key. How can I get it from private key? Thank in advance!